# cPanel - Moving mails to another host

Tags: email, transfer, cpanel

I need to transfer about 20 addon domains and their email accounts to a new host, where I already have some sites, mail accounts, databases etc..

For some reason, I think that my best bet is to transfer the mail accounts manually, like copying **etc** and **mail** folders from old to new host via FTP. Now, while this works very well, I have one problem: all transferred mails again have unread flag (like there were never opened).

Now my question is: Is there a way to move mail accounts while in same way preserve ***read/unread*** flags?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open a mail client and add both old and new accounts side by side (with IMAP) you can drag the mails from one to the other - it's a pain but I've had to do it that way in the past.

Other that that you could take the email on to Google Apps and use their selection of migration tools to accomplish the task.

Comment: :D I ll try this actually

Comment: It's a pig, but it works!

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to find out where the read/unread flags are stored, but the unix program [imapsync](http://linux.die.net/man/1/imapsync) seems to be designed to migrate email accounts from one imap server to another while preserving message attributes/states.

Comment: Thanks! But unfortunately I don't have shell access :(

Comment: @RhymeGuy: Yeash... Almost all shared hosting packages provide shell accounts (DreamHost provides unlimited shell accounts, and their shared hosting is less than $9/month). Any web host that doesn't provide shell access is highly suspect in my book. But if for some reason you want to switch from one subpar web host to another subpar web host, I guess you could just ask one of the web hosts to do the migration for you. It shouldn't be very hard for them to do this, and it's probably a fairly common request--especially if they don't provide shell access.

Comment: They offered me migration, problem there is because I already have about 10-15 sites hosted with them, and some settings and files would be overwritten.

Comment: That's pretty poor customer service if they can't migrate just the emails for you.